# Creating a command that concatenates an input string token by token

Tags: macros, xparse, parsing

Using (first of all) `xparse` I want to create a command like this:

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\c}{ s > { \SplitList { ; } } r""}
{
% do something
}
```

It basically should just do the following:

- convert `"f;g;h;..."` to `f » g » h » ...`, if s is false (no star is given)
- convert `"f;g;h;..."` to `fgh...`, if s is true (a star is given)

The whole purpose is being able to redefine the command to basically reverse the order, that is:

- convert `"f;g;h;..."` to `... « h « g « f`, if s is false (no star is given)
- convert `"f;g;h;..."` to `...hgf`, if s is true (a star is given)

How can I nicely do this using "high-level functions"? I am already using `xparse, xstring` and I am thinking `etoolbox` or something similar might help. I do not really want to deal with "low-level" TeX programming, if that makes any sense.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for using a delimited argument instead of the standard braces?

Comment: @egreg Not particularly. I guess it looks better and it is little bit easier to type. Oh, it also may improve readibility, when you have nested commands (when you use multiple kinds of delimiters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really 'high-level' but since `xparse` is used anyway and `SplitList` is `expl3` anyway:

The `\convert` command uses the first starred argument for the `f>g>h` splitting and the third argument is for reversal of the order.

It uses a `\seq_...` variable and splits the input by `;` into tokens and glues them together (or replaces effectively `;` by `>`) and eventually reverses the order.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\convert}{sr""s}
{
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {;} {#2}
  \IfBooleanT{ #3 }{%
    \seq_reverse:N \l_tmpa_seq 
  }
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {}%
  }{%
    \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {$>$} 
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\convert"f;g;h"

\convert*"f;g;h"

\convert*"f;g;h"*

\convert"f;g;h"*


\end{document}
```

[image]